# Cannot plot GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib, plot

I am new to geopandas and having trouble plotting geometry. I have searched the forum and none of the other questions address this issue.

```
import shapely.wkt
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('../google_footprints.csv.gz', compression='gzip')

# convert string geometry
data.loc[:, 'geometry'] = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(data.loc[:, 'geometry'])

# convert pd.DataFrame -> gpd.GeoDataFrame
footprint_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry='geometry')
```

Once I have done this I am able to successfully plot individual polygons like so:

```
footprint_gdf.loc[[9096691],'geometry'].plot()
```

[image: geometry plot]

But plotting the entire gdf does not work (it just shows a blank plot). I've tried all of the following:

```
footprint_gdf.plot()
footprint_gdf['geometry'].plot()
footprint_gdf[:, 'geometry'].plot()
```

[image: blank plot, just showing axes]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Versions and details:

- Working in Colab
- shapely==1.7.1
- geopandas==0.10.2
- matplotlib==3.2.2

Comment: `footprint_gdf.buffer(0.05).plot()` shows any result?

Comment: It does! But not the results I'd expect, unfortunately (it's just one big circular blob).

Comment: Check that your projection and coordinates are what they are supposed to be? Your axes look a little suspect.

Answer (score 3):

Your data probably spreads over a large area. It plots something, but footprints are not displayed since the image is too small. Try to plot a bigger image using, for example:

```
footprint_gdf.plot(figsize=(20,20))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was unrelated to this code. I had been filtering the data using inappropriate values for the min/max lat/lons.